# Laravel, SQL varchar

Tags: laravel, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, laravel-migrations

I am Using laravel with MS SQL. When string datatype is defined in the migration (code attahced) laravel create a nvarchar datatype in the Database instead of varchar. How to restrict laravel or SQL Server to create varchar datatype when a datatype of string is defined in migration.

Following is the code for migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ie_applicant_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('applicant_type_id');
        $table->string('applicant_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and sqlsrv is default in config/database

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv')
```

but still nvarchar data type is created when the migration is run instead of varchar. SQL Pic attached

[image: Datatype created on running the migration]

Comment: Did you by any chance found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use string , there it is :

```
$table->string('name');
```

It`s will work for you .

Comment: datatype string is defied for varchar but still SQL server create a datatype of nvarchar. Migration DB code is attached along with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database type in `config/database.php` file.

The default is MySQL, but if you are using MS SQL, it should be `'default' => 'sqlsrv',` in database.php

Comment: sqlsrv been already set in the config/database as default while running the migration. But still you can see as the attache image shows migration create a datatype of nvarchar instead of varchar

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an older question, but putting an answer in for anyone stumbling upon this.

The nvarchar is hard-coded. The beauty is that this is all just PHP, so you can change that. If you prefer varchar over nvarchar, just change it in laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/SqlServerGrammar.php

Just change the nvarchars in there to varchars.

Unfortunately, there's nothing in the migration stuff to give you control over this on a column-by-column level. You'd have to choose up front to leave it nvarchar for everything or nvarchar for everything.